# If a wave cannot resonate, why can its Fourier transform do?

Tags: fourier-series

I understand that Fourier series approximate the input signal well and series converge to the original function. If the system is ODE, such as $x''+Ax'+Bx=f(t)$, then $f(t)$ will respond differently to each term of the series according to how close its frequency is to the system natural frequency and thus one of the term will resonates with $f(t)$.

But why can an original input without natural frequency, such as square wave function, can resonate after being transformed? Where is the source of resonance in the original input signal, if it doesn't have in the first place?

[image]

Comment: I can't understand your question. Can you rephrase? What exactly do you mean by resonance?

Comment: @ZacharySelk: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance

Comment: I can Google/use Wikipedia. I'm asking what YOU mean by resonance.

Comment: Large amplitude of output at input frequencies near the natural frequency.

Comment: What's the output you're talking about? A Fourier series approximates a signal. I don't know where output comes into play.

Comment: In ODE such as $x''+Ax'+Bx=f(t)$, where $f(t)$ is a periodic function. Is my question clear now ?

Comment: the main Fourier series theorem is that $\{e^{2 i \pi n t}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2([0,2\pi])$, so $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n e^{2 i \pi n t} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{2 i \pi n t}$ for every $t \implies a_n = c_n$ for every $n$. finally use that $x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n e^{2 i \pi n t} \implies $ $x''(t)+Ax'(t)+B x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-4 \pi^2n^2 + A 2i \pi n+B) a_n e^{2 i \pi n t}$ and $f(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{2 i \pi n t} $ to obtain $a_n = \frac{c_n}{-4 \pi^2n^2 + A 2i \pi n+B}$

Comment: So you have an ODE driven by $f$. You Fourier expand the $f$ and you're looking at the solution, $x$. Then the frequencies of $f$ that are closest to the frequency of the solution are the largest in the solution. Then your question is, why does this happen? Do I have your question right?

Comment: overall $$x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{2 i \pi n t}}{-4 \pi^2n^2 + A 2i \pi n+B} \int_0^{2 \pi} f(x) e^{-2 i \pi n x} dx$$

Comment: @ZacharySelk that's right. The frequency of the original input signal -without approximating it by Fourier- is far from natural frequency and thus no resonance should happen. But when approximating it using Fourier resonance shows up. How could this happen ?

Comment: @user1952009 I'm not asking how to get Fourier series, I'm asking about the behavior of the response.

Comment: if you don't say what you don't understand, nobody can help you, and really the answer is in what I wrote

Comment: I'm not doing engineering, but can square wave resonate in principle? With another squared $f(t)$, or with a sine one?

Comment: @reuns I think the question is interesting, and have edited it to highlight the problem. Can you come and see? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The natural frequency is given by $\omega_{0}=\sqrt{B}$.

If a periodic signal $f(t)$ with frequency of $n$-th harmnoic (or $n-1$ overtone) equals to the natural frequency, then the corresponding terms contribute to resonance.

Mathematically, say for example

$$f(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} \sin n\omega t$$

if $\omega_{0}=n\omega$ then the term (partial signal) $a_{n} \sin n\omega t$ contribute to the resonance solution.

In case of a single pulse (or wavepacket), Fourier transform should be used instead.

Comment: The questing is edited to highlight the exact problem the OP has. Can you come and see? Thank you.

Comment: For periodic wave, there won't be resonance when $\omega_{0} \ne n\omega$.  For a single pulse (or wave packet), there's continuous spectrum for all frequencies (with corresponding amplitudes and phases).  Say a Gaussian pulse in Fourier space $$e^{-a(\omega-\omega_1)^2t}$$ it's highly resonated when $\omega_1 \approx \omega_0$, otherwise no obvious resonance occurs.

Comment: Is your guassian pulse the system itself, or the external force? When you say "no obvious resonance occurs", does it mean that responses do occur, they're just insignificant for all terms?

Comment: No, it's in $\omega$ space.  You may do the inverse Fourier transform to get back the signal.